# PHP - Class 'My\Engine\Control' not found

Tags: php

The following code is included by another file. `My\Engine\Control` is defined much earlier and extended all throughout my site with no issues. However in this one file I get the the error:

> Fatal error: Class 'My\Engine\Control' not found in
>   /mnt/web/~/classes.php on line 6

```
<?php
namespace My\Engine;

// class Control {}

class RequiresAccount extends Control {
    public function permissions() {

    }

}
```

Yet when I try to put a dummy Control class in (uncomment the commented part) I get a different error.

> Fatal error: Cannot declare class My\Engine\Control, because the name
>   is already in use in /mnt/web/~/Control.class.php on line 47

It seems impossible and I just can't figure it out. I write code like this all the time and just this one time...

All other files that require extending `\My\Engine\Control` function perfectly.

Comment: What else does the file have? What's *different* about this file comparing with the others where it does work?

Comment: @ishegg I deleted everything else in the file and the error persists. There's no difference between this file and any other file other than the contents of the class.

I can't create because it exists, I can't use because it doesn't exist. I've never seen anything like it and it confusing the h. out of me.

Comment: And do you have your class empty like in the example? Or does it have some code in it? It's certainly head scratcher! Did you try changing the file's name (just to try something)?

Comment: @ishegg I'm just an idiot it appears. I due to some twisted logic decision I guess I made a long time ago some code was being executed much earlier than it should have ever been. I'll have to go back and re-factor that. After 15 years working with the language and using this code base for quite a number of years without incident I guess I was overconfident.

To identify my issue I started pasting the following code around the place until I found where the working and non-working code samples diverged.

var_export(class_exists( '\\Gravy\\Engine\\Control' ));

Comment: I'm glad you got it sorted out!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your using some custom autoload logic and some kind of optimizer which puts all the classes together into one file.
I would suggest sticking with [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) standard & [Composer](https://getcomposer.org) library to support and maintain it.

This way your files will be organized and composer will take care of properly handling loading the files and optimizing the loading process for production. All you need to do is to include `./vendor/autoload.php` file into your project and define the auto-loading strategy in `composer.json` file.

Comment: Issue had nothing to do with autoloading. It was more an issue of:  
A requires B,  
B requires C,  
C requires A,  

No matter what I did there was no solution, I eventually created a D and refactored a bit.